# Getting error in MVC Proj while writing Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

i am creating a sample movie (MVC) application. I was getting fine with Viewing and Creating a new record, but when i wrote the code to get the details of a particular record i met with the following error:

```
Unable to cast objec`t of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[MovieApp.Models.Movie]' to type 'MovieApp.Model`s.Movie'.
```

here is the code i wrote for getting the details

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var moviedetail = (Movie)_entities.MovieSet.Where(mvid => mvid.Id == id);
return View(moviedetail);
}
```

can any body tell me whats going wrong and where ??

thank you.

Comment: Where returns a query which is not executed until you do a ToList() or something like that, you could simply add .First() at the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is the Where function returns you IEnumerable and you are typecasting it to Movie. Therefore it is failing. Check for syntax of Where extension function to see for yourself. So if you are sure that you will only be returned one Movie object, I suggest you use First() like this.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id) 
{ 
    var moviedetail = _entities.MovieSet.Where(mvid => mvid.Id == id).First(); 
    return View(moviedetail); 
}
```

Comment: 100% perfect answer!

thanks buddy, this is exactly what was happening...and i tried out as you said and now my code is running smoothly...

thanks a ton for the answer !!

take care

Answer (score 1):

do 
`var moviedetail = (Movie)_entities.MovieSet.FirstOrDefault(mvid => mvid.Id == id);`

`Where` is used to return a list, add ToList() and you'll have all the items that matches your id, if your sure there is only one, use `First`, it will return the first item that matches, `FirstOrDefault` will return the first that matches or your default object (probably null) if there is no match.

Comment: Or Single(...) if you know there's going to be one and only one.

Comment: hey buddy,
appreciate your help, but i have already tried the solution you mentioned above and i got this message 

(The method 'Single' is not supported by LINQ to Entities. Consider using the method 'First' instead.)

and thats the reason i was using the WHERE property

any clues ???

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are getting a collection from the lambda expression. And your view is expecting a single movie object. Since there is a mismatch, it is throwing the error. Just use Single() instead of Where() or use First().

var moviedetail = (Movie)_entities.MovieSet.Single(mvid => mvid.Id == id);

Comment: hey buddy,
thanks for the answer but the first or single property will return me either the first or the default single object.
where as i want the object that matches the id and hence the where clause...

any other clues that i can try ??
thanks